# I have installed linux version of MATLAB but being new I have no idea how to run it. There is no exec file as in windows

Tags: matlab

I have executable matlab in bin/glnx86 folder.
What is the next step?

Comment: Did you check your Unity or Gnome desktop if there is a shortcut for running it? And please check this [link](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-AT26VI/index.html?solution=1-AT26VI)

Comment: Installing the Linux version is different then Windows or Mac OS near the end of the install at the top of the screen it will have a box to check for simulinks.  Did you check the box?  If not I recommend re-installing.

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on matlab file, go to Properties, Permissions, and make sure 'Allow executing file as program' is enabled. Then double-click on matlab and it ought to open.

Answer (score 0):

When a program is installed on your system, you may simply type its name (or something similar when it is not obvious) in a terminal emulator. So, according also to [this source](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-AT26VI/index.html?solution=1-AT26VI), you may open a terminal emulator from your applications menu, type just `matlab` and press enter.

If this does not work, you may start MATLAB from its installation directory. Use the commands `cd foo` to change the directory to "foo" and `ls` to list the files and directories in your current directory. For example: `cd /usr/local/matlab/R2009b/bin`. And then, type `./matlab` to run matlab that is located on the current directory.

In your case, it must be `cd bin/glnx86` and `./matlab`.

You may also create a launcher for your applications menu, according to your desktop environment.